# Наречие или прилагательное?

Tags: грамматика, прилагательные, наречия, раздельно-дефис

> Жена встретила меня без трусов и со сковородкой в руке, т.е. не по
>   нормальному.

В данном случае надо писать "по-нормальному" или "по нормальному", проще говоря, наречие это слово или прилагательное?

Comment: В руке была сковородКа или сковорода?

Comment: Да ну ЕТМ, давайте поговорим о погоде вообще.

Answer (score 1):

Встретила как? По-нормальному. Это наречие.

Советую посмотреть: [Разница между наречием и прилагательным](https://thedifference.ru/kak-otlichit-narechie-ot-prilagatelnogo/).

Правило гласит:

> Пишутся через дефис наречия с приставкой по-, образованные от полных прилагательных и местоимений и оканчивающиеся на — ому, — ему, — ки, -ни, — ьи

В дополнение: *т. е.* пишется с пробелом.

Comment: Не похоже тут оно на наречие. Здесь вполне допускается раздельное написание по смыслу, если автор делает акцент на "НЕ по нормальному".

Comment: Ну, похоже не похоже, а все-таки наречие. Отвечает на вопрос( как?). А вот здесь НЕ наречие: "пошел не по нормальному пути".

Comment: @ДенисФедоров, Если Вы уверены, что "вполне допускается раздельное написание", то зачем вопрос задали? Других участников экзаменуете?

Answer (score 1):

***По-нормальному*** ― это наречие, если считать по-нормальному. (В смысле ― по-нормированному, хотя такого слова вроде бы нет).

**Для того и существует наречие**, чтобы обозначить направление, но при этом не указывать конкретный предмет, его обозначающий: **встретить по-нормальному** ― это встретить по нормальному обычаю/ритуалу и т.д.

Пользователи русского языка вполне **одобрительно относятся к этому слову**

http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EF%EE%20%ED%EE%F0%EC%E0%EB%FC%ED%EE%EC%F3&p=4

**Пример**

Я бы хотел учиться в Москве, видаться с Валей и Митькой и чтоб все шло **по-нормальному.** [Г. С. Эфрон. Дневники. Т. 1. 1941 (1941)]

Comment: Жасмин, Вы мои мечты на русский язык убиваете.

Comment: Ну, Вы же романтик, а я янус многоликий, сейчас вот слежу за порядком. Я тоже  люблю свободу, но свободу  цивилизованную, в рамках правил (это как поэт, который пишет стихи в рамках заданной формы). Кстати, тут в одной статье есть ваш портрет: http://psihomed.com/romantik/   По-моему, похоже.

Comment: Вы правы, Принцесса Жасмин, я еще и симпатичный романтик.

Comment: Тогда будем дружить.  Задавайте нам интересные (романтические и поэтические) вопросы, а то у нас одна проза вроде "ставить запятую или нет".